# TeamViewer and Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, teamviewer

I was trying to Install Team Viewer 6 in Windows 8 it got installed but I am unable to take control of another Remote PC.Is there a stable version of Team Viewer for Windows 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Team Viewer Modern UI App. Search for it in the Windows App Store to install it, or you can find more info on [its listing in the Windows Store website](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-ph/app/teamviewer-touch/417cca6d-744d-4770-b168-12171f73ed37).

Note, I'm pretty sure this only works as a client (viewer). It doesn't work as a server for Team Viewer on the Windows 8 machine it's installed on.

[image: team viewer touch]

Answer (score 2):

Team Viewer is available for download from Windows 8 Main screen and available in Windows Store.Just Search and Download it.

Answer (score 1):

TeamViewer is available. The stable version is 7.0.

> TeamViewer is a simple and fast solution for remote control, desktop sharing and file transfer that works behind any firewall and NAT proxy

[Download Link](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The TeamViewer for Windows 8 can be found [here](http://www.teamviewer.com/download).

The Team Viewer Team has achieved Windows 8 Certification that means it can be installed in Windows 8 without any hiccups.

> Tampa, Florida, August 22, 2012 – TeamViewer®, one of the world’s most popular providers of remote control and online meetings software, today announced it has achieved Windows 8 certification which makes TeamViewer available to users on the latest Microsoft operating system.